# Canvas not showing image after drawImage() called

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I am writing an educational programming environment (partly for my own experience, partly for my students).

As part of this environment, I am trying to place an image onto a grid. The grid draws fine, however the image does not appear. No error appears in the console.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Grid!</title>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <script src="grid.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="510" height="510" >Your browser does not support HTML canvas.</canvas>
        <input type="button" id="go" value="Go" onclick="drawGrid();">
    <body>
<head>
```

And Javascript (not sure what might be needed, so I added everything I have so far). The debug alert that I have when the dog image is drawn does not display.

```
//The walls arrays
var wallsX = new Array();
var wallsY = new Array();
var wallsO = new Array();

//The canvas variables
var c;
var ctx;

//The dog position variables
var doxX;
var dogY;
var dog;

//Load the dog image
dog = new Image();
dog.onload = function() 
{
    alert("Image loaded");
    //Draws the dog
    c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(dog, 10, 360, 40, 40);
}
dog.scr = "img\dog.png";


function start()
{
    //Temporary start function
    readWalls();
    buildWalls();
}

function buildWalls()
{
    //This function cycles through all of the walls and calls a function to display them
    var cnt = wallsX.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        placeWall(wallsX[i], wallsY[i], wallsO[i]);
    }
}

function placeWall(xLoc, yLoc, orientation)
{
    //This function places the wall onto the canvas based on it's position
    //Set the stroke colour
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle= "#FF0000";

    //Determine the start x and y coordinate of the wall
    var xCo = getWallCo(xLoc);
    var yCo = getWallCo(yLoc);
    var tmp;

    //Draw the wall
    if (orientation == "horizontal")
    {
        ctx.moveTo(xCo, yCo);
        tmp = xCo + 50;
        ctx.lineTo(tmp, yCo);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    else
    {
        ctx.moveTo(xCo, yCo);
        tmp = yCo + 50;
        ctx.lineTo(xCo, tmp);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function getWallCo(loc)
{
    //This function returns the coordinate based on the wall location
    var val = 0;
    switch (loc)
    {
        case 0:
            val = 35;
            break;
        case 1:
            val = 85;
            break;
        case 2:
            val = 135;
            break;
        case 3:
            val = 185;
            break;
        case 4:
            val = 235;
            break;
        case 5:
            val = 285;
            break;
        case 6:
            val = 335;
            break;
        case 7:
            val = 385;
            break;
        case 9:
            val = 435;
            break;
        case 10:
            val = 485;
            break;
    }
    return val;
}

function drawGrid()
{
    //This function draws the initial grid in the canvas space
    c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle= "#000000";
    var xCo = 10;
    var yCo = 10;
    var tmp;

    ctx.rect(10,10,500,500);
    //Print vertical lines on the canvas
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        ctx.moveTo(xCo, yCo);
        tmp = yCo + 500;
        ctx.lineTo(xCo, tmp);
        ctx.stroke();
        xCo += 50;
    }
    //Print horizontal lines on the canvas
    xCo = 10;
    yCo = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        ctx.moveTo(xCo, yCo);
        tmp = xCo + 500;
        ctx.lineTo(tmp, yCo);
        ctx.stroke();
        yCo += 50;
    }
    //Temporary start function
    start();
}

function readWalls()
{
    //These lines are sample walls
    wallsX[0] = 5;
    wallsY[0] = 7;
    wallsO[0] = "horizontal";
    wallsX[1] = 6;
    wallsY[1] = 6;
    wallsO[1] = "vertical";
    wallsX[2] = 6;
    wallsY[2] = 6;
    wallsO[2] = "horizontal";
}
```

Any help is much appeciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in this function :

```
dog.onload = function() 
{
  alert("Image loaded");
  //Draws the dog
  c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(dog, 10, 360, 40, 40);
}
```

You do

```
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Should be

```
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: Thanks for that (this was left over from when I was debugging). I have fixed that error, however I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

How did you try your code? On server or not?

If you did not access the html by server,maybe cross-origin problem occurred.

Or you can change your html to this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grid!</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

<head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="510" height="510" >Your browser does not support HTML canvas.</canvas>
    <input type="button" id="go" value="Go" onclick="drawGrid();">
    <script src="grid.js"></script>
<body>
```

Comment: I have been accessing it locally for the most part, however I have tried it on a server as well and I get the same result. I have also tried moving the script to the end of the HTML file, but same result.